# Automatic conversion from a for-loop to a while-loop for "basic" for-loops

Tags: scala

It's known that using a for-loop:

```
for (i <- 0 until 10)
 do()
```

is much slower than using a while-loop:

```
var i = 0
while (i < 10)
 do()
```

Is there a way for me to make the compiler automatically convert a for-loop of that simplicity into that equivalent while-loop?

I'm not looking for anything fancy, just a way to convert simple for-loops like the one given. I'm sure there must be a way to maybe write a macro for Eclipse/IntelliJ to do that, or something for the compiler itself, since it is opensource so I would imagine such things are possible.

Comment: The `-optimize` flag may do this in some cases—to be honest I've never used it seriously, and it seems to be something of a minefield. You're probably better off with something like [Spire](https://github.com/non/spire)'s `cfor`.

Comment: @TravisBrown No matter what I do, I cannot get spire to work. I'm just writing the following simple code:
  cfor(0)(_ < 10, _ + 1) { i => println(i) }


I always get the following error:
Error:(74, 11) spire.syntax.cfor.type does not take parameters
      cfor(0)(_ < 10, _ + 1) { i => println(i) }
          ^

Comment: That sounds like you imported the package object, which has the same name as the macro (which I agree is a little confusing). Try importing `spire.syntax.cfor._` (or just `spire.syntax.cfor.cfor`).

Comment: that would then give "macro implementation not found"

Comment: Odd—that definitely should work (I just confirmed). Might be worth a new question with your Scala, Spire versions, etc.